# Google maps not showing correctly

Tags: google-maps

I have a styled map using the api, and it's not showing correctly:

If you click on contact in the top right a map should appear below the contact form:

http://machinas.com/wip/machinas/website/v21/

It appears but half of the map area is just grey. Any ideas why this might be?

Thanks!

This is what I see:

http://i42.tinypic.com/2ntafwp.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting up your map in a function called `initialize()`, which is called when the page is loaded by this line of code:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

However, your `map-canvas` element is not yet sized properly, because it has `width:100%` and it is a child of the `.contact-overlay` element which has `display:none`.

Remove that line of code, and instead call `initialize()` explicitly after you click the Contact Us link and the slide-open area appears. Once that is visible and sized, then initialize the map with the `initialize()` call.

This will also help your page load faster, since it won't initialize the map on every page load, only when the contact overlay panel is opened.